# New limitation of 30 total permissions on registered applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azureportal

The blade in the portal: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade/quickStartType//sourceType/

If you edit a registered app in this preview blade and add API permissions you will hit the limit on number 30. This limit is enforced across the total of all API's.

The fact that Graph alone has more than 30 delegated permissions makes this absolutely stupid and will break integration between applications.

Does anyone why this is planned on being enforced as it is extremely restrictive and will break any future integration plans?

Microsoft support told me that it is preview, and yes it is, but this is what they are planning and it concerns us.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restriction will be removed for apps that only support Azure AD accounts. For apps that support both Azure AD accounts and personal Microsoft accounts this limit will continue to be enforced.

Comment: What about "Accounts in any organizational directory"?

Comment: For "Accounts in any organizational directory", the 30 permission limit will be removed

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully they update the more info in the portal before it is released and clearly state this limitation in the updated documentation.